# Jenkins setup for xamarin froms app in mac build for ios

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration

i am trying to setup jenkins job for xamarin.froms app and added msBuild plugin in jenkins configurations.

Create a job and trying to build the ios app, here is the build command i am using

```
msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" \ 
    /p:Platform="iPhone" \ 
    /p:IpaPackageDir="$HOME/Builds" \
    /t:Build Sample.sln
```

build are failing saying that

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

what is the exact command to build ios app ?

Comment: If `Build Sample.sln` is even the real name of your solution, you might want to try it without spaces, or find a way to escape spaces in the filename.

Comment: Sample.sln is the file name there is no spaces in file name

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistakenly took the build parameter as part of the filename :) Where are you executing this? In the folder where the source is located? It might be wise to state the full path to the sln file

Comment: the build command is in jenkins jobs, i'm new to jenkings, this is the reference i'm following, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/jenkins-walkthrough

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [MSBuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) you can do it like so:

1. Add the build step:

[image]

1. Add the following:

   1. Select the MSBuild version from the drop down, this is set in your Jenkins Configuration.
   2. The Path to your solution file from the root directory
   3. The command line parameters (I removed the line escapes). I changed `$HOME` to `%WORKSPACE%`

You should have something like this:

[image]

If you want to just run the bash command, you will have to move to the directory with where the solution file is then run:

`msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:IpaPackageDir="$HOME/Builds" /t:Build Solution.sln`

**Make sure you have set the environment variable $HOME if that is where you want it to go**

If not change `$HOME/Builds` to another path.